# REISUB cause hard disk IO error

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 , when I restarted by using Alt + SysRq + R +E+I+S+U+B, Ubuntu fails to boot, it show;
Unexpected inconsistency and tells me to manually run fsck on /dev/sda2 the / of Ubuntu. Then it shows me busybox console where I run fsck. Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title may not be clear, I think that actually your hard disk is not having any I/O errors, instead the  problem is that you have an inconsistent Filesystem because Ubuntu didn't shutdown properly.

Maybe you typed very fast the REISUB sequence?  What about pressing REISUB more slowly?  Mmm, Have already run fsck and rebooted? Is it still failing to boot?

Comment: It booted when I ran fsck, but when I rebooted again it showed the same messages.(Even rebooting normally)

Comment: +1 for REISUB slowly. VERY slowly. These actions are far from instantaneous (depending on what the machine is doing, of course...). Allowing processes to terminate gracefully and syncing data to drives should be given time.